# new to android development- cant start a new activity

Tags: android, android-intent

First- sorry if my question a bit dumb, I'm totally new to Android development ...

I'm trying to start a new activity from my "LAUNCHER" activity and run it on the emulator, but every time I click on the "Next" button (which should start my second activity), I get an error msg saying: "unfortunately, Omis hang man free has stopped", and then closes the app...
also, when I re-launch the same app in the emulator without re-installing it from Eclipse, it doesn't even showing me the first screen...

I don't even know where my problem lies, so I attached 5 codes:

1'st activity layout (named "activity_open")

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".OpenActivity"
    android:background="#DCDCDC" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="30" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvEnterName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/stEnterName"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="40" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etNameInput"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/stHintNameEnter"
            android:singleLine="true" />

    </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="30" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bNext"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/stNext"
    android:textSize="24sp" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

1'st activity class (named "OpenActivity")

```
package com.omi.hangmanfree;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class OpenActivity extends Activity {

TextView tvEnterYourName;
EditText etName;
Button bContinue;
String myName, tmp;
final String errorStr = "\nYou must enter a name!";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_open);

    initialize();

    bContinue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myName = etName.getText().toString();

            if(etName.getText().toString().equals("") == true)
            {
                tvEnterYourName.setText(tmp + errorStr);
                tvEnterYourName.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }
            else
            {
                try {
                    Intent gameIntent = new    Intent("com.omi.hangmanfree.GAMEACTIVITY");
                    startActivity(gameIntent);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

private void initialize() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    tvEnterYourName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvEnterName);
    etName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etNameInput);
    bContinue = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bNext);
    myName = "~";
    tmp = tvEnterYourName.getText().toString();
}



@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();

    finish();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_open, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

2'nd activity class (named "GameActivity")
    package com.omi.hangmanfree;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class GameActivity extends Activity {

TextView tt;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

    GridView gvGrid = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gvHagdara);
    tt.setText("_");
    gvGrid.addView(tt);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_game, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

2'nd activity layout (named "layout_game")

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".GameActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gvHagdara"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerInParent="false"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit" >

</GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

5. manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.omi.hangmanfree"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".OpenActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".GameActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_game" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.omi.hangmanfree.GAMEACTIVITY" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

**I'm not looking for code improvements (I am only learning the language), so please do not send me suggestions to improve the code (I know there are a lot!) --- I just want this code to work.**

Comment: As you are new: Open the LogCat view in Eclipse to get the stack trace and post it here.

Comment: 11-30 11:22:04.087: E/AndroidRuntime(2374): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Comment: 11-30 11:22:04.087: E/AndroidRuntime(2374): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.omi.hangmanfree/com.omi.hangmanfree.GameActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-30 11:22:04.087: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
11-30 11:22:04.087: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
11-30 11:22:04.087: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)

Comment: 11-30 11:22:04.087: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
11-30 11:22:04.087: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-30 11:22:04.087: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

Comment: 11-30 11:22:04.087: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
11-30 11:22:04.087: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-30 11:22:04.087: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

Comment: 11-30 11:22:04.087: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-30 11:22:04.087: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-30 11:22:04.087: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-30 11:22:04.087: E/AndroidRuntime(2374): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-30 11:22:04.087: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):  at com.omi.hangmanfree.GameActivity.onCreate(GameActivity.java:18)

Comment: 11-30 11:22:04.087: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
11-30 11:22:04.087: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
11-30 11:22:04.087: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
11-30 11:22:04.087: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):  ... 11 more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem may be in the Intent. Try this:

```
Intent gameIntent = new Intent(OpenActivity.this, GameActivity.class);
```

Comment: can you tell me what is the problem in current code?

Comment: didn't help... same problam

Comment: post your logcat trace to see the exception you get.

Comment: posted it below my question

Comment: I see now. The problem was not in the Intent, but in the TextView in GameActivity. That tt is null when you try to set its text. Try to create it first: TextView tt = new TextView(getApplicationContext());, then you can call tt.setText("_");

Comment: did you find the problam by looking at the logCat? if so, where exactly?

Comment: here, line 18:11:22:04.087: E/AndroidRuntime(2374): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 11-30 11:22:04.087: E/AndroidRuntime(2374): at com.omi.hangmanfree.GameActivity.onCreate(GameActivity.java:18)

Answer (score 2):

Please Remove `finish();` from `onPause()` Method from OpenActivity and remove `gvGrid.addView(tt);` from GameActivity because gridview is not container layout and write below code

```
Intent gameIntent = new Intent(OpenActivity.this, GameActivity.class);
startActivity(gameIntent);
```

instead of

```
Intent gameIntent = new    Intent("com.omi.hangmanfree.GAMEACTIVITY");
startActivity(gameIntent);
```

it will solve your problem.

Comment: tnx for the tip about the gridview, but it didn't help my problam... same error

Comment: @omi Add this code line tt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1); before tt.setText("_");, it will solve your problem.

Comment: YES! THANK YOU! that was the problam...

Answer (score 0):

please replace in openActivity

```
Intent gameIntent  = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GameActivity.class);
startActivity(gameIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing here:

```
           Intent gameIntent = new    Intent("com.omi.hangmanfree.GAMEACTIVITY");
            startActivity(gameIntent);
```

to

```
                Intent gameIntent = new    Intent(OpenActivity.this, GameActivity.class);
                startActivity(gameIntent);
```